# Windows 10 uninstallation

Tags: windows-10, boot, uninstall, bootable-media, hp-elitebook

I have a HP Elitebook 8440p(BIOS Legacy) which had Windows 7 preinstalled, but later I installed some linux distros, and finally installed Windows 10. But now, I am unable to boot from my usb device(to install other linux distro). When I click USB in boot options, it boots into Windows 10.

I cant access the bios as well, because I dont have the bios administrator password. Is there any way to uninstall Windows 10 now? Or is there anyway to boot from my USB?

Windows 10 is painfully slow in this laptop, so I want to use another linux distro, or install Windows 7 again.

Comment: Are you sure the usb is bootable? BIOS will try to boot from all devices you set in the Boot Order option. If one fails it tries the other. Also please provide details about the BIOS version.

Comment: Yes it is bootable, I tried it on another laptop(UEFI boot). Can you please tell where to find bios info?

Comment: So from http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02441315 you'd either need the BIOS admin password or call HP to get help with the reset, which given the age of the laptop might result in no help at all.

Comment: Does removing the cmos battery remove the password?

Comment: In a consumer laptop yes, but these Enterprise ones have enhanced security features. Maybe give this a try: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03593792.

Comment: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03453264.pdf explains the security features for HP Enterprise notebooks

Comment: Or can I just delete Windows 10? If yes how?

Comment: Something is up.. have you tried a NON-UEFI boot device?  The operating system can't override your boot device order.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get a non-uefi boot device?

Comment: I use Universal USB Installer to make bootable USBs, should I use something else?

Comment: OMG! It's working now! I used Rufus, and it is booting from the USB now! But can I know why UUI wasnt? Because I previously did boot from UUI bootable USBs.